# same php file but in different folders display different outputs

Tags: php, mysql

i have a really odd thing going here. I have a single php file that i have called index2.php (i'll give the code below) I have this file in two different directories, when i load then both in my web browsers i get two different outputs. Can someone please tell me how this is possible!?

```
 <?php
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 // DJ Status v3.0                                               //
 // ©2012 Joseph Scocca                                          //
 //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 include ("config.php"); // include the settings to connect to DB and ShoutCast
 include ("header.php"); // include the Header info
 if ($scsuccs!=1) { // Check is we can connect to ShoutCast Server
 if($streamstatus == "1"){ // Is the Stream broadcasting 
 if (isset($dj)) { // is there a DJ in the DB connected

 // Open Container and Column 1
 echo "<div id=\"container\"><div id=\"column-1\">";

 // connected DJ have a Avatar
 if (isset($djavatar) && $djavatar) { echo "
 <div id=\"avatarpic\"><img src=\"$djavatars/$djavatar\" /></div>"; }    

 // Close Column 1 Open Column 2 Make the Div Stats and start showing data
 echo "</div><div id=\"column-2\">
 <div id=\"stats\">
 <div><strong><span>Now playing</span></strong></div>";


 // if the song title is longer than 17 characters then scroll the title
 if (strlen($artisttitle[1]) > 17) { echo "
 <div><marquee behavior=\"scroll\" scrollamount=\"1\" direction=\"left\" width=\"160\">$artisttitle[1]</marquee>    </div>";

 // if the artist is longer than 16 characters then scroll the artists
 if (strlen($artisttitle[0]) > 16) { echo "
 <div><strong>By </strong><marquee behavior=\"scroll\" scrollamount=\"1\" direction=\"left\" width=\"135\">$artisttitle[0] </marquee></div>
 <div><strong>On Air</strong> $djname </div>";

 // if the artist is short than or equals 16 characters then just display it as text
 } else if (strlen($artisttitle[0]) <=16) { echo "
 <div><strong>By </strong>$artisttitle[0]<div>
 <strong>On Air</strong> $djname </div>";}

 } else if (strlen($artisttitle[1]) <= 17) {    
 echo "<div>$artisttitle[1]</div>";
 //if the song title is less than 17 characters then just display it as text

 // if the artist is longer than 16 characters then scroll the artists
 if (strlen($artisttitle[0]) > 16) { echo "
 <div><strong>By </strong><marquee behavior=\"scroll\" scrollamount=\"1\" direction=\"left\" width=\"135\">$artisttitle[0]</marquee></div><div><strong>On Air</strong> $djname </div>";
  // if the artist is short than or equals 16 characters then just display it as text
 } else if (strlen($artisttitle[0]) <=16) { echo "
 <div><strong>By </strong>$artisttitle[0]<div><strong>On Air</strong> $djname </div>";
            }
    } 
 echo "</div></div></div> // Close Column 2, Stats, and Container.
 <div id=\"column-3\"><div id=\"social\">"; // Open Column 3 and social
    if (isset($address) && $address) {echo "
 <a href=\"$address\" target=\"_blank\">
 <img style=\"height:25px;width:94px;\" src=\"images/request.png\" border=\"0\" />
 </a><br>";} //  requestline 

 if (isset($djname1) && $djname1) {echo "
 $djname1";} // Display the DJ Name (for shows that Have a Co Host.)
 if (isset($twitter) && $twitter) {echo "
 <a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/$twitter\" target=\"_blank\">
 <img src=\"images/twitter.png\" border=\"0\" /></a>";}
  // does the  DJ have a Twitter, if so display it

 if (isset($facebook) && $facebook) {echo "
 <a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/$facebook\" target=\"_blank\">
 <img src=\"images/facebook.png\"  border=\"0\"/></a>"; }
 // does the  DJ have a Facebook, if so display it

 if (isset($email) && $email) {echo "
 <a href=\"mailto:$email\"><img src=\"images/email.png\"  border=\"0\"/></a>";}
  // does the DJ have a Email, if so display it

 // if the Connected DJ has a Co Host do the following.
 if (isset($djname2) && $djname2) {echo "
 <br />$djname2";} // Display the Co Host Name

 if (isset($twitter2) && $twitter2) {echo "
 <a href=\"http://www.twitter.com/$twitter2\" target=\"_blank\">
 <img src=\"images/twitter.png\" border=\"0\" /></a>";} // Co Host Tiwtter 

 if (isset($facebook2) && $facebook2) {echo "
 <a href=\"http://www.facebook.com/$facebook2\" target=\"_blank\">
 <img src=\"images/facebook.png\"  border=\"0\"/></a>"; } // Co Host  Facebook 

 if (isset($email2) && $email2) {echo "<a href=\"mailto:$email2\">
 <img src=\"images/email.png\" border=\"0\" />";} //  Co Host email 

 echo "</div></div>"; //Closing of the Social Div and Column 3

 } else { // when the current dj is not in the system do the following

 echo "<div id=\"container\"><div id=\"column-1\"><div id=\"avatarpic\">
 <img src=\"$djavatars/default.png\" /></div>";
  // Open Container, Column 1, and avatar pic. Display the default avatar 
 echo "</div><div id=\"column-2\">";   // Close Column 1, Open Column 2

 echo "<div id=\"stats\"><div><strong><span>Now playing</span></strong></div>";
 // Make the Div Stats and start showing data

 // if the song title is longer than 25 charaters then scroll the title
 if (strlen($artisttitle[1]) > 17) { echo "
 <div><marquee behavior=\"scroll\" scrollamount=\"1\" direction=\"left\" width=\"160\"> $artisttitle[1]  </marquee></div><div><strong>By:</strong> $artisttitle[0]</div>";

 } else if (strlen($artisttitle[1]) <= 17) {echo "
 <div>$artisttitle[1]</div><div><strong>By:</strong> $artisttitle[0]</div></div>";}   
 //if the song title is less than 25 charaters then just display it as text

 echo "</div>"; } // Close Column 2

 } else {echo "<b><span style=\"color:#FFF;\">Trek Radio is currently experiencing
 <br />technical difficulties.<br /> Please check again later. (Error 100)</b>
 </span>";} // Error 100 connetion error to the DB

 } else {echo "<b><span style=\"color:#FFF;\">Trek Radio is currently experiencing
 <br />technical difficulties.<br /> Please check again later. (Error 200)</b>
 </scpan>";} // Error 200 connection error to shoutcast
 echo "</div>"; // Close Container
 ?>
```

Now this script should give my the current song title and dj that is currently on the air. What I dont get is, when you go to http://www.surayamedia.com/onair_tr/index2.php   and http://www.surayamedia.com/trdjs/index.php  the output are different. How can this be when it is the same exact file? They are just placed in two different directories! I don't get it.  All I am trying to do is to move the script to a different folder on the server!

Thank you for who ever can figue out what can be done to fix this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a server issue not a code issue.

Comment: please elaborate on what was exactly the cause of your issues. sometime, someone might benefit from the information you supply here. writing just "server issue" isn't likely to help others.

Answer (score 0):

You have includes that are in the same directory as the script, so it looks like the one that doesn't show the DJ is missing one or both of the includes. Instead of duplicating the includes you could store them in a separate directory, perhaps above the public html.

```
include ("config.php");
include ("header.php");
```

Move into `includes` above the public html:

```
include ("../../includes/config.php");
include ("../../includes/header.php");
```

If the includes are present in both directories then it means there is some code in the includes that is dependent on relative paths.

Comment: i understand what you saying here, but the two directories are identical. They have every file in its correct place, but they are just displaying diffrently.

Comment: There is something in the includes that is dependent on relative paths then. The script you posted is not the problem, all it does is create HTML, it's the includes.

Comment: The directory /onair_tr and /trdjs  are identical I have copied all files from onair_tr to trdjs. The only thing that has relative paths are the fonts and the scrolling js files, and as you can see they both work just fine.

Comment: You need to debug the includes, find where the DJ name is populated, and trace it back, see what the difference could be.

Comment: well also if you look all the way to the right you also see the twitter logo again only on the file that is in the onair_tr folder. Both of these are populated in config.php as it looks at the mysql db and find all the current dj info and if it is defined i nthe db it will display it on the page